# Вывести больше на 5 секунд фактической даты

Tags: java, hibernate

Как вывести больше на 5 секунд фактической даты, возможно ли так сделать?

Причина, есть Дата создания и Дата закрытия. Дата закрытия вносится в БД раньше на считанные секунды. Т.е. при нажатии на кнопку Завершить Дата закрытия обгоняет Дату создания, причем у Даты Создания в БД - sysdate.

```
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    private Date date_end;
    
. . .

    public Date getDate_end() {
        return date_end;
    }

    public void setDate_end(Date date_end) {
        this.date_end = date_end;
    }
```

PetitController.java

```
    if(para.trim().equals("Завершить")){
        if(petit.getPresentId() == 2 && petit.getBloutboindletter2016().getDate_response().equals("")){
            petit.getBlockger2016().setState(2);
            if(petit.getBloutboindletter2016().getResponsible().equals("")){ petit.setUsername(getUserName());}
            else{petit.setUsername(petit.getBloutboindletter2016().getResponsible());}
        }else{
            
            if(petit.getPresentId() == 2 && !petit.getBloutboindletter2016().getDate_response().equals(""))
            {
                petit.getBlockger2016().setState(3);
                
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.S");
                petit.getBlockger2016().setDate_end(df.parse(petit.getBloutboindletter2016().getDate_response().concat(" 01:00:00.123")));
                
                if(petit.getBloutboindletter2016().getResponsible().equals("")){ petit.setUsername(getUserName());}
                else{petit.setUsername(petit.getBloutboindletter2016().getResponsible());}
            }
            else{
                    petit.getBlockger2016().setState(3);
                    petit.getBlockger2016().setDate_end(new Date());
            }
        }
    }
```

Например в БД

```
09.07.2021 12:41:04
```

Нужно

```
09.07.2021 12:41:09
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно:

```
int seconds = date_end.getSeconds();
date_end.setSeconds(seconds + 5);
```

Но и `getSecond()` и `setSeconds()` помечены как устаревшие и вместо Date предлагается использовать класс Calendar. Тогда можно так:

```
Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
int seconds = end.get(Calendar.SECOND);
end.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds + 5);
date_end = end.getTime(); // конвертация в Date()
```

Comment: Не трогая формат? Мне не желательно менять формат.

Comment: так тут нигде формат вообще не затрагивается

Comment: собственно формат и сама дата это независимые вещи. Вы один и тот же объект (хоть Date, хоть Calendar) можете вывести в любом нужном вам формате даже в одной строчке.

Comment: Т.е. последний вами предложенный код вставить в главный класс, где создается date_end?

Comment: Да, думаю, что в ``setDate_end()``, если я правильно все представляю.

Comment: Но можно и первый код туда вставить, он тоже работает.

Comment: Из первого, предлагает создать @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") и не нравится точка после date_end и закрывающийся ковычка

Comment: У второго к getInstance предлагает создать метод в Canendar.java? , SECOND - предлагает создать constant в Canendar.java
И ругается на seconds + 5 - Syntax error on tokens, TypeArgument1 expected instead

Comment: не понимаю, о каких кавычках речь, в моем коде никаких кавычек нет. Для второго кода нужно импортировать ``java.util.Calendar;``.

Comment: перепутал т.е. скобках

Comment: вы куда-то не туда вставили и в коде до этого не закрыта одна или более скобок.

Comment: Вставил там где set и get. Ругается на строчку end.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds + 5); На скобки и на seconds + 5(Syntax error on tokens, TypeArgument1 expected instead)

Comment: оба фрагмента кода правильно работают, когда расположены просто в main(). Поскольку вы их вставляете внутрь другого класса и в его методы, то понятное дело, скорее всего, придется этот код немного подкорректировать. Как именно - я не могу сказать, потому что у меня нет вашего остального кода.

Comment: Мне нужно найти main класс. Я на него вышел где public static void